# Non-increasing function $f$ implies $f'\leq 0$

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, solution-verification

We are tasked to prove the following "Assume that $f$ is continuous on $[a, b]$ and differentiable on $(a, b)$. If $f$ is non-increasing is it true that $f' \leq 0$?"

Note: We have a theorem in our lecture notes (theorem a) that states: if $f'>0$ then $f$ is strictly increasing.

I attempt to prove the question by contradiction.
Proof:
Suppose, towards a contradiction, that we have $f$ is non-increasing on $[a,b]$ and that $f'>0$. Then clearly by theorem a, $f$ must be increasing. Which contradicts our assumption. Hence the original statement is true.

Is my proof correct?

EDIT: Would contrapositive work instead?

Comment: Yes, that works

Comment: Great, thank you @Lorago.

Comment: Is the question, "If $f$ is non-increasing is it true that $f' \leq 0$ on $(0,1) ?$", or is the question, "If $f$ is non-increasing is it true that $f' \leq 0$ on $[0,1] ?$" ?

Comment: @AdamRubinson it does not specify.

Answer (score 1):

No, your proof is not correct.
The assumption is that for all $x$, $f'(x)$ is non positive. The negation of this assumption is that there exists an $x$ such that $f'(x)$ is positive.

There exists functions that are neither increasing on $[a,b]$ nor decreasing on $[a,b]$! They can fluctuate on the interval, being increasing in some part and decreasing in other parts.

Comment: +1 to this answer. The comment above is incorrect.

Comment: If $P \implies Q$ is true, then isn't the logical structure for contadiction $P \implies \text{not}Q$ is false?

Comment: @HungaryGoose P implies Q is equivalent to not Q implies not P.

Comment: No. $P \Rightarrow Q$ is the same as $(not\ P)\ or\ Q$. Its negation is $P\ and\ (not\ Q)$.

Comment: Okay thank you for the input everypne.

Comment: Noted @cloudy. In this case, would contrapositive work instead? E.g. $\text{not }f \leq 0 \implies \text{ f is strictly increasing}$?

Comment: Yes, you can try to prove the contrapositive instead. not $f' \leq 0 \Rightarrow$ f is increasing. Note that in english, increasing means strictly increasing.

Answer (score 0):

Your proof does not work as stated by coudy and other people above: "not $f'>0$" does not mean $f'\leq 0$.

Here is correct proof.

Since $f$ is non-increasing, then $f(x+\epsilon)\leq f(x)$ for any $\epsilon>0$.

$f'=\lim_{\epsilon\to 0^+} \frac{f(x+\epsilon)-f(x)}{\epsilon}$

$f'\leq0$.